# How to remove the header from a p:panel?

Tags: html, css, primefaces

Hello i've been exercising in Primefaces and got stuck with the UI , i don't know if I'm weak in CSS or i haven't yet familiarized with the library of primefaces.

[image]

IMAGE1

As you can see in the image i wanted to make the separator fully fitted to the panel(IMAGE1). I also wanted to make the header which contains "data" to be not visible. I've already tried to delete the header="data", but it will be not having a top border of the panel(IMAGE2).

[image: IMAGE2]
IMAGE2

Here's the code

```
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
                xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
                xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
                xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
                xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
                template="/WEB-INF/template.xhtml">
    <ui:define name="content">

        <p:panel style="border:none;">
            <!--        FROM HERE-->  

            <h:form id="form">
                <p:dataGrid var="jab" value="#{homeMBean.listJabatan}" columns="3" layout="grid"
                            rows="12" paginator="true" id="jabatanid"
                            paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport}  {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {RowsPerPageDropdown}"
                            paginatorPosition="bottom"
                            rowsPerPageTemplate="6,12,16" style="border:none;">

                    <p:panel header="data" style="text-align:center;border-width: 0">
                        <h:panelGrid columns="1" style="width:100%" > 

                            <h:outputText value="#{jab.jabatanAdministrasi}" />
                            <h:outputText value="#{jab.jabatanKppn}" />
                            <h:outputText value="Aktif" rendered="#{jab.active eq true}"/>
                            <h:outputText value="non aktif" rendered="#{jab.active eq false}"/>
                            <p:separator style="margin-left: 0px" />
                        </h:panelGrid>
                    </p:panel>

                </p:dataGrid>

            </h:form>
            <!--TO HERE-->
        </p:panel>
        
                    
    </ui:define>
</ui:composition>
```

Answer (score 1):

This requires a better knowlegde of CSS development. You need to dig deeper, which would lead you to a style rule set by the theme:

```css
body .ui-panel .ui-panel-content {
  border-top: 0 none;
}
```

You need to override that style as explained in [How do I override default PrimeFaces CSS with custom styles?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8768317/how-do-i-override-default-primefaces-css-with-custom-styles)

Also, if you want to use a headerless panel consistently, I would advise to `styleClass` the panel to make it reuseable. Or simply use a `h:panelGroup` or a `div` with a class, because basically you are after a (rendered) `div` with a border and some padding.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove `header="data"`

and replace your style something like that

```
<p:panel style="text-align:center;border:1px solid #d8d8d8;">
```

the header will disappear and the border will remain.

Comment: This will give you an extra border on the panel content, which already has a border at the left and the right side.

Comment: So you can just use border-top:1px solid #d8d8d8; instead, but I tried that and it does not looks like you describe, have you tried that?

Comment: No, you need to override the `body .ui-panel .ui-panel-content` rule, and there set the top border.

Comment: This will override the css rule. Component style in xhtml has a bigger priority -> you don't need to override file css rule.

Comment: It will set the style to the outer `div` rendered by the `p:panel`, not to the panel content. Try it. I did. It doesn't work.